# Is there a way to adjust the size of the footnote bar in Beamer

Tags: beamer, titles, resize

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamersize{text margin left=5pt,text margin right=5pt}

\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{boxes} }
%\usetheme{FrankKurt}

\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,comment}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title[{\makebox[.45\paperwidth]{\hfill%
        Very Very very very Very Very very very long long long long long title \hspace{.2in}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}]{Very Very very very Very Very very very long long long long long title}

\author[Author Name]{}
\vskip -.5in

\date{}% to not show date

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just use a short title for the footer?

Comment: The short title may not carry the full meaning of the full title. If this is not possible, then I probably just leave it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the optional argument of `\title` to specify a shorter title.

However, if you wish to change the width of the boxes in the footer, you need to look at the template defined for the `footline` when you `\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}`. For that, we look at [`beamerouterthemesplit.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesplit.sty):

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{split theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

Note how there are two `beamercolorbox`es defined. The first (left) has a width of `.5\paperwidth`, as does the second (right). Below I changed this 50:50 ratio to 35:65:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{boxes} }

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

% Update footline template to have a 35:65 ratio in the boxes
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.35\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.65\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\title
  [Very Very very very Very Very very very long long long long long title \hspace{.2in}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]
  {Very Very very very Very Very very very long long long long long title}

\author[Author Name]{}
\date{}% to not show date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I need. I am aware of the option using the short title but I want to learn if it is possible to adjust the length of the footnote bar. Thanks you very much!